# K-Means Clustering for telecom customers behavioral usage

Tags: machine-learning, k-means, large-data

I am trying to run K-means clustering on a dataset of 100k records and 26 columns. My problem is in the visualization or plotting clusters part. Since I have several features, I couldn't specify the x and y axis. How can I perform k-means for all the records and not just specific features?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

For "performing k-means" you don't need visualisation. You can just run it, 26 columns are not a problem. How you can "perform" it and how to visualise the result are two different questions. You could visualise the result for example on the first two principal components.